# Is there a way to manually process a DispatchQueue in iOS

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

I'm working on a game that I'm wanting to add cloud saves via GameKit. The original save code was based on synchronous file I/O and blocks the main queue. Moving away from this design would be a massive amount of work. Unfortunately, it seems like the GameKit APIs dispatch callbacks on the main queue which causes a deadlock in this case.

Given this, is there a way to manually process the blocks in a dispatch queue? That way the blocking code could process the main queue while waiting for the callbacks, eliminating the deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a chain of responsibility using Operations. Setup the dependencies between each operation, and then drop them in their respective queues using Grand Central Dispatch.

UI code should be in main and there’s Quality Of Services for background tasks and USER generated activity. You can create a dispatch queues and set them to be synchronous (serial) or asynchronous (parallel).

If you include code, I will post examples. Otherwise there’s several options on how to do the above.